# How to access object property inside an nested array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

How can i access the property `fm` and `lm` which is inside an mobile array.

```
array=[
       {
        "name":"siddhesh",
        "mobile":[{"fm":"83******","lm":"78******"}]
       }
     ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `array[0].mobile[0].fm`

You can just use regular array and object accessors:
 - Having an array named `arr = []`, you can get any member of it by `arr[index]`.
 - Having an object named `obj = {}`, you can get any property of it by `obj.propertyName`.

Therefore:

```
// array
const a = array[0];
// object
const b = a.mobile;
// array
const c = b[0];
// object
const d = c.fm;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if there's more than only one object inside your `array`, use following solution:

```js
var array = [{"name":"siddhesh","mobile":[{"fm":"83******","lm":"78******"}]},{"name":"another","mobile":[{"fm":"23******","lm":"18******"}]}],
    res = [].concat(...array.map(v => v.mobile.map(Object.values)));

    console.log(res);
```